# Managing directory permissions across the host and Docker container environments

Tags: linux, permissions, docker

I'm trying to use a stack built with Docker container to run a Symfony2 application ([SfDocker](https://github.com/advancingu/SfDocker)). The stack consists of interlinked containers where ubuntu:14.04 is a base:

- mysql db
- nginx
- php-fpm

The recurring problem that I'm facing is managing directory permission inside the container. When I mount a vloume from the host, e.g.

```
volumes:   
- symfony-code:/var/www/app
```

The mounted directories will always be owned by `root` or an unidentified user (only user ID visible when running `ls -al`) inside the container.

This, essentially, makes it impossible to access the application through the browser. Of course running `chown -R root:www-data` on public directories solves the problem, but as soon as I want to write to e.g. 'cache' directory as from the host (where the user is `ltarasiewicz`) I'd get `permission denied error`. On top of that, whenever an application running inside a container creates new directories (e.h. 'logs'), they again are owned by`root` and later inaccessible by the browser or my desktop user.

So my question are:

1. How I should manage permission accross the host and container
   environments (when I want to run commands on the container from both
   environments) ?
2. Is it possible to configure Docker so that directories mounted as volumes receive specific ownership/permissions (e.g. 'root:www-data') automatically?
3. Am I free to create new users and user groups inside my 'nginx' container built from the Ubuntu:14.04 image ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few general points, apologies if I don't answer your questions directly.

- Don't run as root in the container. Create a user in the Dockerfile and switch to it, either with the USER statement or in an entrypoint or command script. See the [Redis official image](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/master/3.0/Dockerfile) for a good example of this. (So the answer to Q3 is yes, and do, but via a Dockerfile - don't make changes to containers by hand).
- Note that the official images often do a [chown on volumes in the entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/master/3.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) to avoid this issue you describe in 2.
- Consider using a data container rather than linking directly to host directories. See the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) for more information.
- Don't run commands from the host on the volumes. Just create a temporary container to do it or use `docker exec` (e.g. `docker run -v /myvol:/myvol myimage touch /myvol/x`).

Comment: I have one more question. I added 'RUN groupadd -r luqo33 && useradd -r -g luqo33 luqo33' to my Dockerfile for the nginx container. I rebuild the container with `docker build -rm .`. But then when I run `groups` inside the running container, there is no `luqo33` group, only `root` - as before. What am I missing here?

Comment: groups returns the groups for the current user, not all users.

Comment: `groups luqo33` (no user), `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
` - there is no user I added through Dockerfile on the list. I'll definitely have to read into Docker docs

Comment: Well, it's a linux thing, not a Docker thing, so you won't find much docs. That should work however. Feel free to open a new question with full info.